# How to check if button was pressed with right click in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-button

I'm trying to make a minesweeper game, and for that the user needs to be able to set flags. In every minesweeperr game, it works with right click. I tried googling and know how to get coordinates of my mouse cursor, but it works weirdly with buttons. Anywhere else, it gives normal coordinates, but when the cursor is over buttons, it gives me coordiantes between 10 and 30. Why is this? I place the buttons in a loop using `.place()`.
Here's the code:

```
def rightclick(event):
    x, y = event.x, event.y
    print('{}, {}'.format(x, y))
root.bind('<Button-3>', rightclick)
```

When I'm not hovering over buttons, it returns normal coordinates like: `452, 539` and `311, 523`

But when I am, it returns: `11, 16` and `30, 11`

Can someone explain what is going on?

Comment: When binding event on root window, the binding will be inherited to its child widgets.  So when you right click on the button, the event is triggered by the button so the (x, y) coordinates will be relative to the top-left corner of the button, not the root window.

Comment: @acw1668 Oh, okay. but then how do I know which button exactly the user pressed? Or is there any way to get the absolute coordinates, not relative to the button?

Comment: `event.widget` is the button widget that triggers the event.

Answer (score 1):

As @acw1668 writes in the comment section the `event.x` and `event.y` return the relative coordinates of `Button` widget due to the inheritance.

You can get the coordinates of root with `event.x_root` and `event.y_root` methods and the `event.widget` returns the widget where the trigger comes from.

**Code:**

```
"""
Example for root/relative mouse coordinates in Tkinter
"""

import tkinter


class App(tkinter.Tk):
    """
    App class from tkinter.Tk
    """

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        button_obj = tkinter.Button(width=10, height=10, background="black")
        button_obj.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
        button_obj.bind("<Button-3>", self.right_click)

    @staticmethod
    def right_click(event):
        """
        Callback method for Right Click on mouse

        Args:
            event: Event object

        Returns: None

        """

        print("Coordinates on the button widget: {}, {}".format(event.x, event.y))
        print("Coordinates on the root: {}, {}".format(event.x_root, event.y_root))
        print("Triggered widget: {}\n".format(event.widget))

root = App()
root.mainloop()
```

**GUI:**

[image: GUI]

**Console output after some right clicks:**

```
>>> python3 test.py 
Coordinates on the button widget: 18, 131
Coordinates on the root: 30, 223
Triggered widget: .!button

Coordinates on the button widget: 27, 57
Coordinates on the root: 39, 149
Triggered widget: .!button

Coordinates on the button widget: 64, 68
Coordinates on the root: 76, 160
Triggered widget: .!button

Coordinates on the button widget: 67, 118
Coordinates on the root: 79, 210
Triggered widget: .!button
```